# Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi: no puedo instalar ninguna aplicación

Tags: android, flutter, vscode, adb

Estoy iniciando con flutter empece bien cree una aplicación de prueba
pero en **Visual Studio Code** precione `Crtl+F5` cuando me parece que solo era precionar `F5` al ver que ya no se instalaba ninguna aplicación me manda el siguiente error constantemente

```
\Error retrieving device properties for ro.product.cpu.abi:
```

investigando dicen entre a la siguiente ruta
**C:\Users\Richard\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools**

y ejecute los siguientes comandos

```
adb kill-server
adb start-server
```

Al usar **PowerShell** con windows 10 me dice que para ejecutar comandos en una ruta es de la siguiente manera

```
.\adb kill-server
.\adb start-server
```

pero el error sigue y no puedo ejecutar ninguna aplicación

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actualmente el Android SDK 29 está presentando problemas. La solución es descargar el directorio platform-tools de la SDK 28. Recomiendo descargarla de alguno de estos enlaces, dependiendo de tu sistema operativo:

Windows: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-windows.zip macOS: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-darwin.zip Linux: http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r28.0.2-linux.zip

Ante todo, es recomendable hacer un backup del actual directorio "platform-tools", la cual se encuentra, si es Windows, en: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk, guardas el respaldo en un lugar seguro. A partir de acá puedes descomprimir según los enlaces facilitados, luego cambias el nombre a la carpeta descomprimida por "platform-tools", la copias, y la pegas en el directorio Sdk, anteriormente señalado, recuerda dar click a Reemplazar. Inicia Android, aplica flutter doctor y verifica que tenga Android SDK 28.x.x. Ya con esta acción funciona correctamente